# React-router v4 optional parameter

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to create an optional parameter url using react-router v4.2.0

I want the url to be like `"/car-rental-service-in-manhattan-new-york" || "/car-rental-service-in-new-york";`

Both url should render pages. Here manhattan is optional.
I was trying the path like path: `"/:keywords-in(-: boroughs)?-:city"`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
let city = window.location.pathname
    .replace('/car-rental-service-in-', '')
    .replace('-new-york', '');

{city ? (
  <Route
    path={'/car-rental-service-in-:city-new-york'}
    exact
    component={PageNotFound}
  />
) : (
  <Route
    path={'/car-rental-service-in--new-york'}
    exact
    component={PageNotFound}
  />
)}
```

Comment: what if new york is also variable?

Answer (score 0):

In order to restrict your parameters in your route, try the following solution.

```
<Route
   path="/car-rental-service-in-:city(york|newe)"
   component={City}
/>
```

To replace the space with hyphen,

```
    var str = this.props.match.params;
    str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

<Route
    path="/car-rental-service-in-:str "
    component={City}
/>
```

If you want to replace space with hyphen is many Components, then you can introduce Higher order component(HOC)

Comment: what i meant is like how to differentiate between manhattan and new york. also what if instead of manhattan some two or three letter word will come like '/car-rental-service-in-:abc-cde-efg-xyz-xyz' .  abc cde efg is a name of single boroughs with space so i want '-' in place of 'space'.  similarly xyz xyz is name of single city. how to differentiate the boroughs and city. so that abc-cde-efg comes in -:boroughs params variable and -xyz-xyz comes to :city params